# Unity C# only one object activated upon trying to activate one of two based on position to the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically in unity C# I have an enemy script that finds the players position relative to the enemy game object and then depending on what side the player is to the enemy activates that melee gameobject while deactivating the one on the other side. However the melee gameobject will only spawn on one side regardless of the players position. This is especially weird considering I have code in the same script that works the same way that has the enemy look towards the player and that works fine. Also the code only activates when the player gets within a certain range and the melee cooldown has ended.

Here is my current code for my enemy melee script:

```
 BasicPlayerMovement target;
    [SerializeField] float agroRange;
    bool isFacingLeft;
    private bool isAgro = false;

    private bool canMelee = true;
    private bool isMeleeing;
    public float meleeTime = 0.1f;
    public float meleeCooldown = 1f;
    private float meleeTimer = 0f;
    private float meleeCooldownTimer = 0f;
    private bool isSearching;

    private float searchTimer = 0f;
    private float timeToSearch = 1f;

    public GameObject meleeColliderRight;
    public GameObject meleeColliderLeft;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //finds player object's location and assigns it to target
        target = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<BasicPlayerMovement>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //distance to player
        float disToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position);
        //timer for how long melee attack lasts
        if (isMeleeing)
        {
            meleeTimer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (meleeTimer >= meleeTime)
            {
                meleeTimer = 0;
                isMeleeing = false;
                meleeColliderRight.SetActive(false);
                meleeColliderLeft.SetActive(false);

            }
        }
        //timer for time between melee attacks
        if (canMelee == false)
        {
            meleeCooldownTimer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (meleeCooldownTimer >= meleeCooldown)
            {
                meleeCooldownTimer = 0;
                canMelee = true;
            }
        }

        if (isSearching == true)
        {
            searchTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (searchTimer >= timeToSearch)
            {
                isAgro = false;
                searchTimer = 0f;
            }
        }
        //if canMelee is true and distance between player and enemy is smaller then agro range enemy looks at and melees player
        if (canMelee == true)
        {
            if (disToPlayer < agroRange)
            {
                isAgro = true;
                
            }
            else
            {
                if (isAgro)
                {
                    if (!isSearching)
                    {
                        LookAtPlayer();
                        Debug.Log("is meleeing");
                        Melee();
                       
                        isSearching = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (isAgro)
            {
                if (disToPlayer < agroRange)
                {
                    LookAtPlayer();
                    Debug.Log("is meleeing");
                    Melee();
                  

                }
            }
        }


    }
    //if enemy facing left .left melee activated else right melee activated
    private void Melee()
    {
        canMelee = false;
        isMeleeing = true;
        if (isFacingLeft == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("left Collider active");
            meleeColliderLeft.SetActive(true);
            meleeColliderRight.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (isFacingLeft == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("right Collider active");
            meleeColliderRight.SetActive(true);
            meleeColliderLeft.SetActive(false);
        }

    }

    void LookAtPlayer()
    {
        //if position of player is left of the player faces left
        if (transform.position.x < target.transform.position.x)
        {
            Debug.Log("facing left");
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(-1, 1);
            isFacingLeft = true;
        }
        //if position of player is right of the player faces right
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("facing Right");
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(1, 1);
            isFacingLeft = false;
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: is it always doing the same side or appearing so because you have flipped your character so like a person if the person in front of you looks the same way you do and raises their right hand, it will be on your right.. if they turn and face you and raise their left.. it will be on your right...